# Layout inside Layout in Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have two layouts like:

```
Layout1 = Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: {
  type: 'handlebars',
  template: Layout1template
},
  regions: {
  region1: '#header',
  region2: '#content'
}
```

});

```
Layout2 = Marionette.Layout.extend({
template: {
  type: 'handlebars',
  template: Layout2template
},
  regions: {
  region1: '#contenttop',
  region2: '#contentbottom'
}
```

});

I want to add Layout2 in Layout1's region2. Or I want to nest layout inside layout. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Layout extends directly from ItemView so creating nested layout is seamless in marionette.

inside onRender of Layout1, you should have this code:

```
onRender: function(){
  this.region2.show(new Layout2({
    ...//code here
  }));
}
```